# Roles Framework isn't working

Tags: asp.net, roles

I installed Role Framework provided by ASP.NET using aspnet_regsql and then configured my application to enable Rules in web.config file using sql server provider :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="gJobs"/>
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

When trying to access the security tab in ASP.net configration tool , I am getting the following error: 
***"The entry 'AspNetSqlRoleProvider' has already been added. (D:\Programming\ASPNETProjects\gJobs\gJobs\gJobs\web.config line 69)"***

I am using the membership api with the same connection string and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<clear/>` before the add element

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/20/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers.aspx

Comment: thanks for replay... connection successfully performed after inserting the <clear />....now I am getting error message when trying to access security tab : "The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: you will need to post more detail

Comment: what details do you ask for in order to post it ?

Comment: unfortunately I get the error without details in security tag page

Comment: This is the whole message ............ There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: what is your connectionstring

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=****\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=gJobs;Integrated Security=SSPI;"  />